# Set in post request javascript and jquery, data and extra parameters

Tags: javascript, post

i try to send a post to php function, the php file can manage the post requests by paremeter called "action", how can insert field called action in the post, this is my post:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: "php/pointsAddOrModify.php",
        data:{
           client: cliente,
           dateInit: dataInit,
           dateEnd: dataEnd,
           factor: factorPoints,
           idComb: idComb
             },
        success: function(data){
           if (data.structure != undefined)
           {
                if(data.status == "OK") {
                    alert("Registro Exitoso");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error intentar de nuevo");//data.message);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

how can add a paremeter called command and their value, this parameter is out of data, by example.

```
   $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: "php/pointsAddOrModify.php",
        command: 'happyHour'
        data:{
           client: cliente,
           dateInit: dataInit,
           dateEnd: dataEnd,
           factor: factorPoints,
           idComb: idComb
             },
        success: function(data){
           if (data.structure != undefined)
           {
                if(data.status == "OK") {
                    alert("Registro Exitoso");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error intentar de nuevo");//data.message);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

is only example but is lilekly to i try, is possible use too a simple post jquery.

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you not understand what this code is doing?  To send a value in the POST, just add it to the `data` object.

Comment: Can you restructure your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, whatever data you want to add as parameter in the service, you can add in `data` object only. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    type : 'POST',
    url : "php/pointsAddOrModify.php",
    data : {
        client : cliente,
        dateInit : dataInit,
        dateEnd : dataEnd,
        factor : factorPoints,
        idComb : idComb,
        action : "action-data", // action param here
        command : "command-data" // command data here
    },
    success : function (data) {}
});
```

You are not allowed to add anything for data/parameter in `$.ajax()`.

Comment: well, ok, and so, is possible make a json and post in another way, even without jquery (ajax and post)?

Comment: yes ofcourse! you can make an ajax using core javascript or using any js library. It's very much possible.

Comment: See the last example of this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-3-events-ajax/